# Excepciones de verbos a pronombres enclíticos

Tags: gramática, pronombres, clíticos

He leído recientemente acerca de los pronombres enclíticos, pero me quedan un par de dudas, cuya respuesta no he podido encontrar. La primera es ¿todos los verbos aceptan pronombre enclítico? En particular tengo la duda con el verbo "entrar", ¿se puede decir "éntrenlo"?

Con respecto a la segunda, además de los casos en que no se usa el pronombre enclítico que vienen en [este enlace](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Pronombre_encl%C3%ADtico):

> 1. En el presente de subjuntivo cuando este tiene carácter imperativo negativo. Aquí ha de ser antepuesto (proclítico):
>
>    - no le digan
>    - no los traigamos
>    - no lo comamos
>    - no la miren
> 2. En todas las formas del indicativo o del subjuntivo en el habla culta corriente. Únicamente es permisible su empleo con fines literarios, aunque también es un rasgo dialectal en el noroeste de España:
>
>    - dígole
>    - trajéreme
>    - púselo
>    - escribiole

¿Existen otros casos donde su uso no sea correcto/apropiado?

Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, Adalid, y bienvenido al sitio. La pregunta parece interesante, pero hay una cosa que no me queda clara. ¿Qué preguntas exactamente? ¿Si hay verbos que no acepten pronombre enclítico en ningún caso? ¿O si hay algún caso de conjugación verbal aparte de los comentados en el enlace que tampoco acepte dichos pronombres? Puedes darle a [edit] para modificar el texto de la pregunta si lo consideras necesario. Por otro lado, deberías copiar aquí la parte relevante del artículo enlazado, en caso de que la página original falle y no podamos comprobar su contenido.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, espero quede más clara y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti por tu pregunta y confianza en nosotros! De momento veo que _entrar_ tiene [una acepción](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FkLKqOW#M395wul) como verbo transitivo equivalente a _introducir_, por lo que si se puede decir _introdúzcanlo_, se puede decir _éntrenlo_. :-)

Comment: Se puede también decir *Éntrenle*.  Esto es parecido a *Quiúbole* (un mexicanismo, creo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todos los verbos, en algunas de sus formas (tiempos, modos) y ciertas condiciones, aceptan pronombres enclíticos. Las reglas son algo complicadas pero básicamente siempre es correcto el pronombre enclítico

1. tras un verbo en imperativo afirmativo: *dame*, *mételas*, *éntrenlo*
2. tras un verbo en infinitivo: *darme, meterlo, entrarlo*.

La regla es igual con un pronombre solo o con dos (*dámelo, métetelas, éntraselo*; *dármela, metérselos, entrártelo*, etc.). Debes tener cuidado de colocar la tilde (el acento agudo) cuando corresponda, ya que añadir un pronombre nunca desplaza la acentuación. Es decir, *entren* se acentúa en la primera sílaba, *en-*, y seguirá haciéndolo si le añades uno o dos pronombres enclíticos, de manera que tendrás que indicar explícitamente el acento en formas como *éntrenlo* o *éntrenselo*, para cumplir con las reglas ortográficas.

Comment: Y también tras un gerundio: *dándome*, *metiéndolo*, *entrándolo*